En .net core Existe alguna otra forma de mantener actualizada la base de datos aparte de esto?
Esta parte del codigo va en program.cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ElecContext2>(options =>
    {
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ElecContext2"));
});

Aqui es donde se agrega la migración
var app = builder.Build();
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ElecContext2>();
    context.Database.Migrate();
}


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! yo particularmente no entiendo a que te referis...
